# Android compose listening for user interaction event globally

Tags: android, events, android-jetpack-compose, user-interaction

Hi I am building one Android application with compose. In my application I want to listen for user interaction globally so that I can place tracking at single place and can avoid placing tracking events at multiple places. For this purpose I want to listener for click and scrolls globally. I tried to create and consume window callback which gives me activity level interaction callbacks but it doesn't give any context on views like which view is clicked. I have provided test tags or layout id under modifier to my view. Currently I am stuck at how to get clicked elements based on these tags so that I can choose my event to register.

I have gone through some of the blogs which mentioned some of the approaches to achieve this [Event listener SDK](https://proandroiddev.com/how-we-built-user-interaction-tracking-for-jetpack-compose-e3b1dd24f0ae). But couldn't find the final solution.